# How to get compass heading in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin, xamarin.mobile

I am trying to get the compass heading on my Android device. Therefore I tried to get the heading with the Xamarin.Mobile component, but as this [thread](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/6834/is-it-possible-to-use-compass) reports the heading is always 0. Is there any other possibility to get the compass heading on my Android device?

Answer (score 3):

Fisrt of all you need to check if you device support CompassHeading, as not all devices support it. So to check, use Xamarin.Geolocation.Geolocator.SupportsHeading, it will return true if device support heading. Also try one of the "compass" apps on the google play to make sure if you device support it.

Comment: My device supports compass heading and I also tested the app in the emulator.

Comment: Have you setted permissions? You have to set the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and also to switch on GPS

Comment: I don't know what happened, but it works now. Thanks anyway for your help.